# SecurityException during executing jnlp file (Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar)

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

OS: Windows 7 64 bit

Java: jdk1.7.0_51

I have a jnlp file. When I double click on this, exception is occurred as below:

```
Application Error: Unable to launch the application
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947458/java-how-to-get-permission-in-java-web-start

Comment: Is this your own app., or is it supplied by others?

Comment: @varun : Your link is outdated 1.7.0_51-b13: [Changes to Security Slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp.html)

Comment: This might also be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449738/long-startup-delay-for-java-webstart-application-since-java-1-7-0u40

Comment: This might also be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449738/long-startup-delay-for-java-webstart-application-since-java-1-7-0u40

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security**

[The JAR file manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html) contains information about the contents of the JAR file, including security and configuration information.

Add the attributes to the manifest before the JAR file is signed.
See [Modifying a Manifest File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) in the Java Tutorial for information on adding attributes to the JAR manifest file.

**Permissions Attribute**

The Permissions attribute is used to verify that the permissions level requested by the RIA when it runs matches the permissions level that was set when the JAR file was created.

Use this attribute to help prevent someone from re-deploying an application that is signed with your certificate and running it at a different privilege level. Set this attribute to one of the following values:

- sandbox - runs in the security sandbox and does not require additional permissions.
- all-permissions - requires access to the user's system resources.

**Changes to Security Slider:**

The following changes to Security Slider were included in this release(7u51):

- Block Self-Signed and Unsigned applets on High Security Setting
- Require Permissions Attribute for High Security Setting
- Warn users of missing Permissions Attributes for Medium Security Setting

For more information, see [Java Control Panel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp.html) documentation.

[image]

**sample** `MANIFEST.MF`

`Manifest-Version: 1.0`
`Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3`
`Created-By: 1.7.0_51-b13 (Oracle Corporation)`
`Trusted-Only: true`
`Class-Path: lib/plugin.jar`
`Permissions: sandbox`
`Codebase: http://myweb.de http://www.myweb.de`
`Application-Name: summary-applet`

Comment: My problem has been solved by "Edit Site List". Thanks moskito-x

Comment: @RiponAlWasim : It's hard to stay on the current. Oracle changes the security settings again and again.

Comment: First. Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and then Configure Java)

Comment: Under Java 8 I wasn't able to run my Java Web Start application. I had to set the same permission level in jnlp file and in manifest (example - Permissions: sandbox). Now it works fine.

Comment: I have this problem would you like to help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356087/java-web-star-java-lang-nullpointerexception-jnlpxargs-execprogram

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to set this globally for all users of a machine, you can create the following directory and file structures:

```
mkdir %windir%\Sun\Java\Deployment
```

Create a file deployment.config with the content:

```
deployment.system.config=file:///c:/windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=TRUE
```

Create a file deployment.properties

```
deployment.user.security.exception.sites=C\:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/Deployment/exception.sites
```

Create a file exception.sites

```
http://example1.com
http://example2.com/path/to/specific/directory/
```

Reference https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in

Comment: The Exception Site list has disappeared for me from the control panel security tab.  This method still worked though!