# Missing permissions attribute in main jar (but it exists in the jar)

Tags: java, jar, manifest, code-signing

**Background**

- main.jar <-- *main codebase*
- util.jar
- HTML Code:

  `<applet id="app" 
           archive="main.jar,util.jar" 
           code="com/business/app/App.class" 
           mayscript="true">
              ... params ...
   </applet>`

**Error**

*"Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar `http://localhost/main.jar`"*

**What I have done**

I signed both jar files with our certificate and running the following is fine.

```
jarsigner -verify main.jar
jarsigner -verify util.jar
```

Also, I included the manifest BEFORE signing the jar files.

In main.jar I have the *MANIFEST.MF* file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: AppName
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
```

I have already taken a look at the following question to no avail

- [SecurityException during executing jnlp file (Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404830/securityexception-during-executing-jnlp-file-missing-required-permissions-manif)

**Question**

I already have the manifest, and it contains the correct permission. Does the order matter in the manifest, and/or are there any other dependencies or causes for the missing permissions manifest error?

**TLDR**

I am getting a missing required Permissions manifest attribute error in my main jar file even though I have included it. What other dependencies exist for the permissions attribute, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. It was a silly issue. The `MANIFEST.MF` file goes under the `META-INF` directory.