# No show anymore message of publisher Java Web Start

Tags: java-web-start

I have developed an application via Java Web Start more or less according to this: [How do I fix "missing Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name manifest attribute" in my JNLP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri) I have packed the jar with manifest.txt, etc..but in this way I have resolved missing attributes problem, and now I have other problem this message is always showed!! I checked "No show again" and each time  I press button to execute and always is showed!! [image] I

Adicionally this is my manifest file:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.zkteco.biometric.AccesoBiometrioAS2
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: http://192.168.111.25:8180/pos-web/
Application-Name: Biometrico

And my Jnlp File this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.111.25:8180/pos-web/">
 <information> <title>CajaPos</title> <vendor>xxx</vendor>
</information>
<security><all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.2+"/>
 <jar href="xx.jar" 
main="true" /> 
</resources
<application-desc main-class="ec.com.xx.pos"  type="JavaFX">
<argument>XY</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

In this page after check the dialog is not showed again  and works fine.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html

Where **XY** change for each request  because I generate jnlp-xml in a dynamically way with a servlet.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to your Java settings. It is a security prompt. There’s nothing you can change in your application to prevent this dialog, it is up to the end-user to change their security settings to show/hide these dialog windows.

Edit: I also recommend migrating your app to a different delivery platform because [Java Web Start is being violently turned off by Oracle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168855/963076)

Comment: Please see my update edit.  Java Web start is nice until all this things. I hope resolved it soon. Thanks.

Comment: It is rare I am discovering that  the problem is the different params (for each execution) that  I send to main method which causes the app "change" and the request is again launched????? please some help and see my update